# alternatives to SSH_AUTH_SOCK for the command line

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

Are there alternatives to the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable for passing agent info to ssh?

What I'm looking for is something like `-o SshAuthSockPath="/path/to/socket"` but nothing like that seems to exist. Am I missing something? Is this somehow a terrible idea?

I'd like to be able to use a different agent for the initial ssh command and ProxyJump connection without needing a wrapper script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `IdentityAgent`.  This was added in release 7.3 (2016-08-01). From the `ssh_config` manual:

```
 IdentityAgent
         Specifies the UNIX-domain socket used to communicate with the
         authentication agent.

         This option overrides the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable and
         can be used to select a specific agent.  Setting the socket name
         to none disables the use of an authentication agent.  If the
         string "SSH_AUTH_SOCK" is specified, the location of the socket
         will be read from the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable.
         Otherwise if the specified value begins with a ‘$’ character,
         then it will be treated as an environment variable containing the
         location of the socket.

         Arguments to IdentityAgent may use the tilde syntax to refer to a
         user's home directory or the tokens described in the TOKENS
         section.
```

Comment: Looks like this is an option added in 7.3. It doesn't look like there's anything comparable in earlier versions

Comment: @PaulRubel Yes, 7.3 (2016-08-01).

Comment: It also looks like the ability to use a dollar-sign environment variable was only added in 7.9.

Comment: @BinaryPhile What are you referring to?